# algorithm for codeforces 559C

Tags: algorithm

I need help with a problem [problem c](https://codeforces.com/contest/1159/problem/C),Although I have a solution But i want to ask If we want to minimize the sweets then 
after assigning these `ans += b[i] * M` sweets we can now say that this is minimum number .
But after that we are assigning again here again `ans += g[i] - b[N]`
Here b[N] is the max number in group of boys
Please help!

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

const int maxn = 1e5 + 10;
int N, M;
long long g[maxn], b[maxn];

int main() {
    scanf("%d%d", &N, &M);
    for(int i = 1; i <= N; i ++)
        scanf("%lld", &b[i]);
    for(int i = 1; i <= M; i ++) {
        scanf("%lld", &g[i]);
    }


    sort(b + 1, b + 1 + N);
    sort(g + 1, g + 1 + M);

    if(b[N] > g[1]) printf("-1\n");
    else {
       long long ans = 0;
       for(int i = N; i >= 1; i --)
            ans += b[i] * M;
        for(int i = 2; i <= M; i ++)
            ans += g[i] - b[N];

       if(g[1] != b[N]) ans += g[1] - b[N - 1];
       printf("%lld\n", ans);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your question should also include the problem description, a description of your strategy for solving the problem, and a summary of how your current solution is failing.

Answer (score 0):

First we sort the girls and boys by min given/max get sweets.
There are 3 steps then:

1 - Each boys give their minimum sweets to each girls.

```
for(int i = N; i >= 1; i --)
  ans += b[i] * M;
```

boys' conditions are fulfilled.

2 - Each girls except the first one get their maximum sweets from the last boy. (Who has the largest minimum, because this way we can minimize the sweets given in this step.) But he had already given his minimum to all of the girls in the previous step, so that's why he gives only the remaining `g[i]-b[N]` sweets here.
*Notice, he cannot add the max to the first girl too, because he needs to add his minimum to somebody.*

```
for(int i = 2; i <= M; i ++)
  ans += g[i] - b[N];
```

girls' conditions (except the first one) are fulfilled.

3 - somebody needs to add the maximum sweets to the first girl. The optimum solution is if the boy with the 2nd largest minimum gives them to her. But it's only needed if the first girl's maximum is greater than the lasts' boy's minimum, otherwise her condition was already fulfilled.

```
if(g[1] != b[N]) 
  ans += g[1] - b[N - 1];
```

firs't girl's condition is fulfilled.

Maybe it's more understandable in this format:

```
for(int i = 1; i < N; i ++)
  ans += b[i] * M;
for(int i = 2; i <= M; i ++)
  ans += g[i];

ans += b[N];

if(g[1] != b[N])
  ans += g[1] - b[N - 1];
```

... however, there are a few corner-cases which are not handled in this algorithm: What is there is only 1 boy or/and 1 girl? (But that's only a few extra if/else branches.)